# Which (if any) NDK libraries/headers are compatible with other toolchains

Tags: android-ndk, cross-compiling, uclibc, musl

I'm working on a project that is compiled using the arm-linux-musleabi toolchain which builds against musl libc. What are my options to use NDK features such as Android jni.h? Am I wrong when assuming that jni.h on Android NDK is not the same as standard jni.h that targets actual Java? I know porting the project to NDK could be the best approach, but let's assume that its not possible for my case. In other words, 'build using NDK' is not an option even though it would be the wiser path. Also note that JNI features are just used as an example,  this question applies to any Android NDK c/c++ libraries that may be used as a drop in with non-ndk toolchains.